# ServiceManager#getService returns null

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have an application service declared in `plugin.xml` as

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <applicationService serviceImplementation="MyService"/>
</extensions>
```

but the following test fails

```
public class MyServiceTest extends LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase {
  public void test() throws Exception {
    MyService service = ServiceManager.getService(MyService.class);
    assertNotNull(service);
  }
}
```

I've tried placing breakpoint with a condition in `DefaultPicoContainer#registerComponent(ComponentAdapter)` but it never triggers. And there are no errors in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin was ignored because there was another plugin in `~\.IdeaIC12\system\plugins-sandbox\plugins` with the same `<name>` in `plugin.xml`.

Inspect `IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl[]` at `PluginManager#initializePlugins` to check if your plugin is being loaded.